# sync SQL CE with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

Hi can anyone suggest how to sync a table in sqlCE with a table in sql server.

I currently have a windows application which uses table X from SQL CE to add new records(a form data) and later when it is connected to network I will need it to update all those newly inserted records to the table Y(equal to table X in CE) in sql server.

The sql CE version is 4.0  and it is not connected to server all the time.The sync needs to be done when it is connected to server on a click event.

The sql server is 2012.

How do I achieve this

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this; which way is best for you depends on things you have not told us, like what edition of SQL Server you are syncing with, whether the app is always connected to SQL Server, whether other apps are also syncing with the same database, and other issues.

I would start by investigating [SQL CE Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171850%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with SQL Server [Web Syncronization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152568%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). If that isn't what you want, come back with more detailed requirements.

Comment: I added more details does that help? Also i would like to keep this as basic as possible since it is only one table I am interested in.

Comment: If you mean SQL Server Enterprise, and if the tables to sync have the same schema, then SQL CE Merge Replication is probably easiest. If you want untrusted third parties to merge data you will probably have to use MS Sync Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ms Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/Sync). It can do everything you need to solve this.